# Buttons, Links, and Actions not being applied to Community (since Digital Experience rename - 1/13/2021)

Tags: lightning-community, action, button-overrides, lightning-action-override

We have an override of our 'Edit' Action on the Case object. In the past, when using the 'Edit' Action, regardless of whether you were logged into the community or not, it would apply our override correctly. Recently, it looks like 'Communities' in setup, was renamed to 'Digital Experiences', and since then, the 'Edit' action override is not working when logged into the community. Instead, it just applies that standard edit action.

Interestingly enough, we have another sandbox where 'Communities' has NOT been renamed in setup, and it still works fine there, so it seems like it has something to do with that change in Salesforce...

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this a Salesforce error, or is there some additional configuration where you can specify the action override by community?

Thanks